# Builder Role on Openshift v3 Online

Tags: git, docker, openshift

I am currently trying to deploy an application on the online version of Openshift (Starter).

My application contains its source-code on Github public repo, and already has a Dockerfile (built and tested on my local docker machine successfully).

Since I already cloned the git repository on my machine, I have just tried this command :

```
oc new-app .
-> [...]
-> error: buildconfigs.build.openshift.io "myapp" is forbidden: build strategy Docker is not allowed
```

So I tried to check and define new role for my account (i am the admin in role bindings )

```
oc policy can-i create buildconfigs
-> yes
oc describe policyBindings :default -n mynamespace
-> [...]
-> RoleBinding[admin]: 
->     Users: myemail@mail.com
oc policy can-i create builds/source
-> yes
oc policy can-i create builds/docker
-> no
```

So I wanted to create a new specific role to create docker builds :

**dockerstategy.yaml**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dockerbuilder
rules:
- resources:
  - builds/docker
  verbs:
  - create
```

But apprently it's forbidden too...

```
oc create -f dockerstrategy.yaml
-> Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "dockerstrategy.yaml": role.authorization.openshift.io "dockerbuilder" is forbidden: user "myemail@mail.com" cannot grant extra privileges
```

I have deployed the same application with the same command locally with Openshift Origin (with the default developer account) and everything was fine.

Is it a global restriction from Red Hat or did i miss something in my account configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift Online doesn't support docker build strategy at this time. This is because providing the feature introduces a security risk to the platform as the build must have elevated privileges. The elevated privileges is so that steps run from the `Dockerfile` to construct the image can be performed as `root`. The risk is that the docker build code has a security vulnerability, in which case a user could become root on a machine within the cluster. Being a shared system you don't own, this would affect more that just yourself and so why it is blocked.

What you can do is build the image on your own system, login to the registry provided by OpenShift for you, and then push the image into OpenShift so you can use it.